# egrep for lines contain certain number of specified character

Tags: regex, unix, grep

I want to write an egrep to grab all the lines that only contain A and B and the number of A's occurrences is divisible by 4!

Comment: **Show us what you've tried so far.**  Don't describe it, but edit the question and paste in the actual code.  Then tell us what didn't work.  What happened when you tried it?  Did you get incorrect results?  Did you get *no* results?  If the results were incorrect, what made them incorrect?  What were you expecting instead?  Did you get *any* correct results?  If so, what were they?  Don't make us guess.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do it:

```
egrep '^((B*A){4})+B*$' filename
```

`(B*A)` matches any number of B's followed by A. `{4}` requires this sequence to appear 4 times. Grouping that and appending `+` allows multiple occurrences of these 4-A groups. Then `B*` at the end allows some number of additional B's on the line.

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick response. I will check it later. Hope you have a good day.